# Silently delete Google Chrome cache

Tags: batch-file

I have this:

```
del "c:\Users\FluffyBunny\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\18.0.1025.162\CACHE_DIR\Cache\*.*" /S /Q /F
```

(deletes temporary files)

But the `18.0.1025.162` directory seems to change every time I update Chrome :(

Can I somehow match any directory that has `CACHE_DIR\Cache\` inside it and delete those files?

Comment: i'm not sure which environment you are using but try using locate command, this may help http://askubuntu.com/questions/33280/use-locate-under-some-specific-directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That `18.0.1025.162` numbers is the Google Chrome's version numbers.
e.g.: Google Chrome v18.0.1025.162.

There are two files you can use to get the current version numbers:

1. ```
   %LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Preferences
   ```

   In `proile.created_by_version` *setting*.
   e.g.: `"created_by_version": "18.0.1025.162"`.
2. ```
   %LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Local State
   ```

   In `user_experience_metrics.stability.stats_version` *setting*.
   e.g.: `"stats_version": "18.0.1025.162"`.

Both `created_by_version` and `stats_version` *settings* seem unique in each file. Meaning that there seem no duplicate with that *setting* name in each file. So you can use `FOR` command to retrieve the numbers.

Answer (score 3):

this seems to have changed at some stage to simply allow

```
del /f/s/q "%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cache\*.*"
```