# Is there a way programmatically clear cache in Chrome without removing Bookmarks, Extensions, and Themes?

Tags: c#, google-chrome, batch-file

I can remove all of the files in %localappdata%\Google\Chrome\User Data using a batch file or C# system.io. The problem I'm running into is that it deletes the bookmarks, extensions, and theme settings. I've tried excluding relevant files with no luck. 
I'm wondering if there is a way to do this, or if it is impossible as they're may be information related to these items in the database file.

Comment: Maybe you're looking for this directory?
%localappdata%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cache

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Silently delete Google Chrome cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12130205/silently-delete-google-chrome-cache)